# Why two objects of a specific class with same properties and functions are not equal in java?

Tags: java

In the below code It prints "NotSame" Can any one tell me the reason thanks in advance...

```
public class student {

    String name;

    student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

public class TestApp{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        student s1=new student("A");
        student s2=new student("A"); 
        if(s1==s2){
            System.out.println("Same");
        }else{
            System.out.println("NotSame");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to override `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` to tell the language how to compare the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s1` and `s2` point to two different Objects having *same* value and **== compares references not the content within the Objects**.

Answer (score 6):

This line:

```
if (s1 == s2)
```

compares the values of the variables `s1` and `s2`. Those values are *just* references. In other words, it's asking whether the values of `s1` and `s2` refer to the same object. They clearly don't, in this case.

To ask for value equality, you'd usually call `equals`:

```
if (s1.equals(s2))
```

However, this will *still* return `false`, as you haven't overridden the `equals` method in the `Student` class. Java assumes object identity for equality unless you tell it otherwise by overriding `equals` (and `hashCode`).

So you could change your code to:

```
// Not name change to follow Java conventions. The class is now final
// as well for simplicity; equality for non-final classes can be tricky.
public final class Student {
    // Equality tests should usually only use final variables. It's odd
    // for two objects to be equal and then non-equal.
    private final String name;

    Student(String name) {
        // TODO: Validate that name isn't null
        this.name = name;         
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (!(other instanceof Student)) {
            return false;
        }
        Student otherStudent = (Student) other;
        return name.equals(otherStudent.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }
}

...

Student s1 = new student("A");
Student s2 = new student("A"); 

if (s1.equals(s2)) {
   // Yay!
}
```

Comment: Jon Skeet You gave me the explanation what I need. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the both are different objects  and they are not `==`. You'll get `"Same"` when both instances pointing to same Object.

A real world example might help you to understand:

Take a ball having color red and say that is a redball1.

Take another ball having color red and say that is a red ball2.

Still both are different balls. :)

And take a ball  having color red and say that redball. Later you define that `"A ball having color red is a redball"`(which is implementing equals method of an Object in your class).

[Proper way to implement equals and it's effects of wrong implementation.](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17)